# Intergrating SMS API for new order in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to integrate SMS API with woo-commerce for every new order but i am not sure where i am doing wrong. My Task is to send SMS to customer when they place order with Payment Gateway C.O.D (Cash on Delivery). Below is the code i am using. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```php
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$customer_id = $order->user_id; 

$billing_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

$data="userid=[userid]&pwd=[password]&msg=[msg]&mobileno=".$billing_phone; 

$jsonurl = curl_init('http://b2bsms.telecard.com.pk/SMSPortal/Customer/ProcessSMS.aspx');

$json = curl($jsonurl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($json);
echo $result; 
curl_close($json);

return $order_id; 
}
```

The error message is

```php
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What error message, stacktrace or unexpected result do you get?

Comment: I am getting this error message

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl()

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `curl` in php, the call to `curl_exec` runs the http call. You can remove the line `$json = curl($jsonurl);` in your code, and use the handle `$jsonurl` everywhere where you are using `$json` or `$ch` at the moment:

```
$jsonurl = curl_init('http://b2bsms.telecard.com.pk/SMSPortal/Customer/ProcessSMS.aspx');
curl_setopt($jsonurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($jsonurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($jsonurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($jsonurl);
echo $result;
```